# RegEx find and replace with sed, matching group and replacing on condition

Tags: itunes, script, regex, sed

Is this possible with sed?

I'm actually in iTunes using "Track Name Edit with sed" from [Doug's Scripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=tracknameeditwithsed), and I have a collection of tracks that are titled in one of two ways:

```
Identical string - Identical string
```

or

```
Some string - some different string
```

In the first case, I want to remove one of the identical strings and the middle `-` so I am left with just a single iteration of the "Identical string." If the strings are different (second case), I want to leave it alone.

I tried `s/^(.*) - $1/$1/`, but it appears I can't match to a group I just defined. `s/^(.*) - (.*)/$1/` will work for the first case, obviously, but will incorrectly process for the second case. Is there another way around this using the tools I've mentioned?

Comment: sed only ever replaces on condition i.e. on condition that it matches! there isn't really a question of how to make sed replace on condition! certainly not in the sense of on condition that it matches, which is what you mean. if you just tried simpler examples you'd soon see that your problem is that it is matching when you think it shouldn't or isn't matching when you think it should.

Comment: do you have a version of sed that uses $1? which version is that? you say  "s/^(.*) - (.*)/$1/ will work for the first case, obviously,"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* reference groups you just defined, but `sed` uses `\n`, not `$n`, for that. In addition, grouping with `(` `)` only works in "extended" mode (enable with the `-r` option):

```
sed -r 's/^(.+) - \1/\1/'
```

In "basic" mode, you'd use:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\) - \1/\1/'
```

Comment: Second option was exactly what I needed! I'm not calling sed myself from within this iTunes applescript, so it appears as though it was running in Basic mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this works , gnuwin32 sed.  GNU sed 4.2.1

```
C:\tes>echo ident - ident | sed -r "s/^(.*) - \1 /z/"
z

C:\tes>echo ident - idrnt | sed -r "s/^(.*) - \1 /z/"
ident - idrnt

C:\tes>echo ident - ident | sed -r "s/^(.*) - \1 /\1/"
ident

C:\tes>echo ident - idevt | sed -r "s/^(.*) - \1 /\1/"
ident - idevt

C:\tes>
```